# How to switch state based on the component id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to import two components into the app and display the contents based on the click of the tab + change title and description accordingly. So far I've got this but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to make this work. What am I missing? I'm fairly new to React and maybe there is a better way to do this.

```
   import React, { Component } from "react";
    import Component1 from "./component1";
    import Component2 from "./component2";


class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            tabs: [{
                id: '1',
                component: <Component1/> ,
                title: 'Component1',
                description: 'This is it'
              }, {
                id: '2',
                component: <Component2/>,
                title: 'Component2',
                description: 'This is another one'
              }],
              activeId: '1'
        };

        this.switchState = this.switchState.bind(this);
    }

    switchState(activeId) {
        this.setState({ activeId });
    }
    render() {
        return (


                                <div className={styles.col}>
                                    <div className={styles.card}>
                                        <div className={styles.cardBody}>
                                            <div className={styles.row}>
                                                <div className={styles.col12}>
                                                    <div
                                                        className={`${
                                                            styles.positionRelative
                                                        } ${styles.formGroup}`}>
                                                        <div
                                                            style={{
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    "bolder",
                                                                color: "#7192a6",
                                                            }}>
                                                            <span
                                                                className={
                                                                    this.state
                                                                        .activeId === '1'
                                                                        ? `${
                                                                            styles.switchState
                                                                        }`
                                                                        : `${
                                                                            styles.switchState
                                                                        } ${
                                                                            styles.unselected
                                                                        }`
                                                                }
                                                                onClick={() => {
                                                                    this.switchState();
                                                                }}>
                                                                Component1{" "}
                                                            </span>
                                                            /
                                                            <span
                                                                className={
                                                                    this.state
                                                                        .activeId === '2'
                                                                        ? `${
                                                                            styles.switchState
                                                                        } ${
                                                                            styles.unselected
                                                                        }`
                                                                        : `${
                                                                            styles.switchState
                                                                        }`
                                                                }
                                                                onClick={() => {
                                                                    this.switchState();
                                                                }}>
                                                                {" "}
                                                                Component2
                                                            </span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className={styles.row}>
                                                <div className={styles.col12}>
                                                    <Component1  
                                                    />
                                                    <Component2

                                                    />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                {/* Caption begins */}
                <span className={styles.priceCalculatorSeparator} />
                <div className={styles.priceCalculatorComment}>
                    <h1 className={styles.title}>{tabs.title}</h1>
                    <hr className={styles.hr} align="left" />
                    <div className={styles.par}>
                        {tabs.description}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you please add code to codesandbox so that it could be easy to understand.

Comment: general advice: don't store the react element in the state directly (your app's state should consist of the `activeId` and the tab ids) instead, create a `Tab` component which receives an `isActive` prop (like `isActive={this.state.activeId === tab.id}`)